# Getting MySQL syntax error using CodeIgniter LIKE active record

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, activerecord, sql-like

This is my code

```
return $this->db
            ->select('organization')
            ->like('title',$this->db->escape_str($query))
            ->or_like('description',$this->db->escape_str($query))
            ->get('shop_search')
            ->num_rows();
```

every thing works well until there is a `'` and NOT `"` in the `$query`.

The error is: `$query="d'"`

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%' OR `description` LIKE '%d\\\\\\'%'' at line 3

SELECT `organization` FROM `default_shop_search` WHERE `title` LIKE '%d\\\\\\'%' OR `description` LIKE '%d\\\\\\'%'
```

What am I missing here?

Dump of passed query:

```
Debug #1 of 1: string(2) "d'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape manually the parameter while you're using CI Active Record Class, Just remove the `$this->db->escape_str()` method:

```
return $this->db
        ->select('organization')
        ->like('title', $query)
        ->or_like('description', $query)
        ->get('shop_search')
        ->num_rows();
```

From CI user Guide:

```
$this->db->like()
```

> **Note:** All values passed to this method are escaped automatically.

### Update

Okay, here's [my test-case](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ebf6/4/0):

```
$query = "e'";
$res = $this->db
            ->select()
            ->like('title', $query)
            ->or_like('description', $query)
            ->get('shop_search')
            ->num_rows();

var_dump($this->db->last_query());
// Output: string(96) "SELECT * FROM (`myPrefix_shop_search`) WHERE `title` LIKE '%e\'%' OR `description` LIKE '%e\'%'"

var_dump($res);
// Output: int(1)
```

As I expected, AR added only one *backslash* to escape the `$query`. I run this test on CI v2.1.4.

Please revise your logic, and if you don't find anything wrong, share more necessary code, I'm all ears.

Comment: Actually, I first tried that but just like now I get the error, ```SELECT `organization` FROM `default_shop_search` WHERE `title` LIKE '%d\\'%' OR `description` LIKE '%d\\'%'``` with your suggested code. After that I added the  `$this->db->escape_str()`.

Comment: What is `$query` exactly? could you post `var_dump($query)`?

Comment: @Youhan I'm making some tests, It may take some mins.

Comment: @Youhan - Alireza :) I just updated my answer. But I didn't face any error. please take a look at the update section.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);

return $this->db
            ->select('organization')
            ->like('title',$query)
            ->or_like('description',$query)
            ->get('shop_search')
            ->num_rows();
```