# Active record query failed - Escape quote from query

Tags: sql, codeigniter, activerecord, pyrocms

**Background**

- Framework: Codeignighter/PyroCMS

I have a DB that stores a list of products, I have a `duplicate function` in my application that first looks for the common product name so it can add a '`suffix`' value to the duplicated product.

**Code in my Products model class**

```php
$product = $this->get($id);

$count = $this->db->like('name', $product->name)->get('products')->num_rows();

$new_product->name = $product->name . ' - ' . $count;
```

On the second line the application fails only when the `$product->name` contains quotes.
I was with the understanding that Codeignighter escaped all strings so I dont know why I get this error.

So I tried to use MySQL escape string function but that didn't help either.

**The Error Message**

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's Book%'' at line 3

SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `name` LIKE '%Harry\\'s Book%'
```

**var_dump**

Below is the output of doing a `var_dump` on `product->name` before and after the line in question;

```
string 'Harry's Book' (length=12)

A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's Book%'' at line 3

SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `name` LIKE '%Harry\\'s Book%'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do some testing about this.

Here is what you are doing

```
$count = $this->db->like('name', $product->name)->get('products')->num_rows();
```

And i suspect `$product->name` contains this.

Harry's Book

As we know this is coming from the database table as you are using.
Where you are using the upper query mentioned it is wrapping it with 
single quotes and producing this result.

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `name` LIKE '%Harry\\'s Book%'
```

As you see it is escaping apostrophy to tell it is not end of string
Therefore escaping it with two slashes.One for apostrophy and one for being in single quote.

What you have to do is 
Before assigning the parameter to query wrap it with double quotes.

```
$product_name   =   "$product->name";
```

And now pass it to query.

```
$count = $this->db->like('name', $product_name)->get('products')->num_rows();
```

The output will be this

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `name` LIKE '%Harry\'s Book%'
```

You see the differece here. It contains single slash now and the record will 
be found.

Comment: I have the exact same problem but this solution does not work for me.

Comment: Even like this it still double escapes the apostrophe: `$product_name = "Harry's Book";`

Comment: I fixed it by passing the raw query to $this->db->query() instead of using like() to build the query, I think this is just a bug in CI Active Record, not something that makes and sense that can be worked around.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers didn't work for me, this does though:

```
$count = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `default_firesale_products` WHERE `title` LIKE '".addslashes($product['title'])."'")->num_rows();
```

Whenever CI Active Record mangles your queries you can always just put a raw query in instead and have full control.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using `stripslashes()` around `$product->name`:

```
$count = $this->db->like('name', stripslashes($product->name))->get('products')->num_rows();
```

CI automatically escapes characters with active records but I bet that it's already escaped if you entered it previously via active record in CI. So now it is doing a double escape.

**Update:** You may also want to try adding the following before you query:

```
$this->db->_protect_identifiers = FALSE;
```

**Last try:** try querying this way since it seems like the `like` active record is causing the error:

```
$like = $product->name;
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `name` LIKE '%$like%'");
```

Comment: can you do a `var_dump()` on `$product->name` before and after the query?

Comment: the first var dump displays what I expect then comes the same error

Comment: I updated my answer, try adding that line of code and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: I get a fatal error:

 Fatal error: Cannot access protected property CI_DB_mysqli_driver::$_protect_identifiers in C:\wamp\pyrocms_test\addons\shared_addons\modules\shop\models\products_m.php on line 202

Comment: Ok. Updated my answer. My last attempt. Lol

Comment: sorry no, that didnt work. Same error. Thanks for your help anyway.